# wt: Document root was not set, or was set to the empty path.

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, wt

I am new to wt(Web Toolkit/witty). When I try to execute hello-world example program [source code](https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/src/hello) , I got the following exception "**Document root was not set, or was set to the empty path. Use --docroot to set the HTML root directory.**" I set the command arguments as "**--http-address=0.0.0.0 --http-port=8080 --deploy-path=/hello --docroot=.**". I capture argument values as "***Arg C = 1 and Arg V = 0000023C3B649E30***" Please help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It is not clear what you are asking. Please clarify your question.

Comment: You can't use `.` (dot) as a docroot. Create a new directory and use it with `--docroot` option.

Comment: Your argc contradicts that you are really specifying arguments. Argc=1 means program was started without arguments. Did you put the arguments in the right place?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you have got the solution. Just to help others.
here is the list of options which you need to give if you are tyring to run your wt web app from cli/terminal in linux.

```
./<your_web_app> --http-address=0.0.0.0 --http-port=8085 --deploy-path=/hello --docroot=.
```

now after go to your browser and open the new tab and give "http://localhost:8085/hello"

should give you your webpage which you are building

Answer (score 1):

Below solution worked for me.

"If you are using Visual Studio you can add them by right clicking on your project, then going to Properties > Configuration Properties > Debugging > Command Arguments.

Open a web browser and go to http://localhost:8080/hello to test your application."

https://andres.jaimes.net/780/how-to-create-a-first-application-using-wt-witty/